# Security on multi page angularjs application - no routing

Tags: angularjs, multi-page-application

I have several html pages, each with an angular app isolated without routing (the app is not a Single Page Application)

```
    //new anguar app in each page
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', …
```

My token is stored into the localstorage so to secure the application i've added in each pages this block of code:

```
app.run(function ($window, $localStorage) {
    …
    if (!$localStorage.currentUser)
        $window.location.href = 'Login.html';
});
```

This approch seems to work, but does exist a better way considering that no routing is used in this application?

Comment: Depends on auth. Explain which one you use.

Comment: I'm using an oauth token saved in the local storage